# Remove iso from external hard drive without losing data

Tags: partitioning, filesystem, dd

By mistake, I used `dd` command on my 1TB external hard drive and made it bootable, with Ubuntu iso image.

```
dd if=iso_path of=/dev/sdbx bs=512k
```

I analyzed the drive, and know that my data is still there.

How can I get it back?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://askubuntu.com/questions/3883/how-to-recover-deleted-files Try https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DataRecovery

Comment: It doesn't solve my problem. My hard drive is bootable now and I can't access the previous stored data through file system. How can I remove the image files and restore my external HD to previous state with all the data it had.

Comment: Although your HD is bootable, you can still boot from a different one. I suggest you boot from a live Ubuntu USB and follow the Data Recovery suggestions in the links. You might be able to recover the partition table or perform a deep scan to recover data. You have copied an iso to your HD so, some of the data may be permanently lost. If you have installed Ubuntu, don't boot and start using it because the system will use the disk and overwrite your previous data. Good luck!

Comment: I ran testdisk on my hard drive. Output: It found 1 "MS Data" partition and says it can't be recovered.